# How to split a string and pass it into your get;set method

Tags: c#, string

I have a web api that accepts a string. The string looks as follows

> 14523:GFTRED3545EDH

Now it gets passed to my command page:

```
public class CaptureCommand : Command
{      
 // how do i split my string in here so that it goes to the correct parameter

    public int id { get; set; }  //pass in 14523

    public string code { get; set; } //pass in GFTRED3545EDH    
}
```

I'm not sure how to split my string up so that ID gets 14523 and code gets GFTRED3545EDH

Your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a constructor that accepts the combination, splits it, and then sets the two properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8). If you're passing it in via the constructor then it'll be like this:

```
public CaptureCommand(string value)
{
  var parts = value.Split(':');
  id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
  code = parts[1];
}
```